# Why is there no 'Circle of Trust' Configuration in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0

I have not found how to configure a 'Circle of Trust' for SAML2 based identity federation in wso2 Identity server.

My scenario is just a single IDP and a SP and create a 'Circle of Trust' and test user account linking.

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what you are trying to do. Can you please explain a bit about your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use default circle of trust in the IDP. As an example in OpenSSO you can use sample circle of trust.

Thanks !
ManulaC

Comment: Thanks Manula : Can you tell me where is the option in the wso2 identity server to do this?

Comment: You can find more details from http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS450/Enabling+SSO+using+OpenSSO+as+the+IDP

Comment: Thanks for answering Manula, but this article talks about openSSO, so do I take it WSO2 does not have the 'Circle of Trust' option?  Is it SAML2 compliant then ? Also I'm not able to figure out how Attribute Mapping and Assersion processing can be done on wso2.

Comment: IS haven't circle of trust option. If you want to add trusted IDP's you can find out more details from http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS450/Trusted+Identity+Providers

Comment: Thanks Manula, So is it SAML 2.0 compliant then ? or is this an optional feature ? Any comments on AttributeMapping and AssertionProcessing?